# Node exec not working | v8.9.0

Tags: node.js, exec

Below code is not working for me. What is wrong here? I am in node v8.9.0

var exec = require('child_process').execFile;
    exec("dir");

Comment: Use the callback to see what is being spat out by the STDOut or STDError

Comment: error message:-{ Error: spawn dir ENOENT
    at _errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:678:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn dir',
  path: 'dir',
  spawnargs: [],
  cmd: 'dir' }

Comment: Are you on windows? You need to promisify the callback (using `util`) or use the callback to access the result, as mentioned above. Beyond that, your error is probably because you're using `execFile` instead of `exec`. The error message should be an edit to the post -- it's hard to read as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exec` or `execSync`:

```
const {execSync} = require('child_process');
const output = execSync('dir').toString('utf8')
```